# ¿Cómo consigo que aparezca el titulo?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No consigo que aparezca el titulo en grande. Solo me aparece en texto muy pequeño

```
alq_vac.hist(bins=20, figsize=(20,20), Color="green", edgecolor="black", grid= False)
plt.title("Tendencia de cada atributo", size=20)
```

Comment: Hola Enrique! Necesitarías poner todo el código para que se te pueda ayudar. No sabemos que es `alq_var` ni de donde viene. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `plt.title()` pone un título al último "subplot". `plt.suptitle()` pondrá un título general.